# How does it store past characters?

Tags: c

Below code recursively calls main and prints entered characters in reverse order. 
I don't understand how past characters are stored in varible c. When new one entered why doesn't past value stored in c overwritten?

```
int main(void) 
{
    char c;
    c=getchar();

    if (c!=EOF)
    {
        main();

        printf("%c",c); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c is local value on stack.

Comment: BTW: c should be declared `int c;`, or your `if (c != EOF)` test will will fail.

Comment: why char fails? I tested it it works

Comment: getchar return value type is int. 
This is to distinguish between the -1 and int 0xff as a character.
type char is not decided or unsigned char or signed char.
No agreement can be reached even through promoted to int if the char is implemented as unsigned char if.(0xFF->255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a variable is local like c is, it is stored on the stack, so every time main is called you get a new copy of c which is then set with getchar.

When the end of file is reached, the function returns, and the previous call of main continues and prints the value.  That call then returns and the previous character is printed until the top level exits.

Here's an example for "abc", the dashes show the stack level

```
main called c set to "a"
-main called c set to "b"
--main called c set to "c"
---eof
---return
--print "c"
--return
-print "b"
-return
print "a"
return
```

Comment: Then as far as I understood in your hello example, there are 5 mains on the stack and each main has a local variable c with different characters right? I was thinking that when I declare c as a variable, whether it is recursive or not , new character is written on the memory allocated for c at the start.

Comment: Not my hello example (moony's), but yes that's right.  If the variable is global, it is allocated at the start. If you'd put c outside of main, it would be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of recursion is that, there is a stack maintained, where the used values in each level is stored. So, the value c is pushed into the stack each time, and popped out while it returns from the depth of recursion

Comment: c is not pushed on to the stack. It's on the stack. After it returns from the depth of recursion, it's pushed on the stack to call printf.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the function is recalled recursive.

As you can see the variable c is defined in the function, so in every call of the function a new variable c is defined on the stack.

So if you read in "hello" the "h" will be stored in the first instance of c on the stack then main is recalled because there is another character in "hello", so the "e" will be stored in the second instance of c on the stack. This goes on until the complete "hello" is read.